# Haskell: Understanding custom data types

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types, custom-data-type

I am trying to make my own custom data type in Haskell.

I have the following data types:

```
type Length = Integer 
type Rotation = Integer 
data Colour = Colour { red, green, blue, alpha :: Int }
            deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I am trying to make a custom data type that can be either one of the data types above. I have the following:

```
data Special 
  = L Length 
  | R Rotation 
  | Col Colour  
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

However, I would like to be able to extract the `Length`, `Rotation` and `Colour` value if I have an instance of the `Special` data type.

If I had:

```
L length
```

Would `length` here be of type `Special` or of type `Length`? If `length` is of type `Special` is there any way to extract it so it's of type `Length`?

For example, is the following code valid?

```
takeL (x:xs)
      | x == (L length) = length
```

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the value"? This is what's called a "sum type" - so it consists of a value *one of* those types, not a collection of them. Concretely, an element might be `L 1` or `R 42` - neither of these can have a `Colour` extracted from them. It may be you want a "product type" instead, which would be `data Special = Special Length Rotation Colour` - where each value of that type has `Length`, `Rotation` and `Colour` values that can be extracted.

Comment: You can just unpack the data constructor.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I don't think I want the data type to be a product data type since I want Special to be either one of Length, Rotation or Colour.

Comment: @ceno980 - thanks for clarifying, in that case your type is indeed correct. But in that case it's not clear what you mean by "extract", since each value will only be able to extract *one* of the three components. If you want to match which one of the constructors it uses, you can do this with pattern matching, or a `case` expression. Regarding your recent edit, in the expression `L length` then `length` must be a `Length` (ie an `Integer`), due to how you defined the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the expression `L length` to be valid, `length` would have to be a `Length` (because  `L :: Length -> Special`).

```
takeL (x:xs)
      | x == (L length) = length
```

is not valid. Unless you've redefined `length` somewhere, `length` is a function `[a] -> Int` from the standard library, so `L length` is a type error.

I think what you're trying to do here is just pattern matching:

```
takeL (L length : xs) = length
```

Answer (score 3):

The data type definition

```
data Special  =
```

reads: `Special` is a new *type* such that to create a *value* of type `Special`,

```
                  L Length
```

- call `L   l` where `l` is a value of type `Length`; or

  ```
              | R Rotation
  ```
- call `R   r` where `r` is a value of type `Rotation`; or

  ```
              | Col Colour
  ```
- call `Col c` where `c` is a value of type `Colour`.

---

To analyze a value of type `Special`, there are three cases to consider:

```
foo :: Special -> ...
foo val = 
    case val of
        L   l -> ...
```

- `l` is a value of type `Length`, in the case `val` was actually `L   l`; or

  ```
      R   r -> ...
  ```
- `r` is a value of type `Rotation`, in the case `val` was actually `R   r`; or

  ```
      Col c -> ...
  ```
- `c` is a value of type `Colour`, in the case `val` was actually `Col c`.

The `case` syntax in function definitions can also be expressed with the pattern based clauses:

```
foo :: Special -> ...
foo (L   l) = ...
foo (R   r) = ...
foo (Col c) = ...
```